# JSON Web Token (JWT) Error: Invalid Signature with RSA Key Pairs

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, jwt

I'm encountering an issue in my Node.js (20.5.1) application related to JSON Web Token (JWT) verification using RSA key pairs. The error message is as follows:

```
[16:39:56.959] FATAL (26460): invalid signature
err: {
  "type": "JsonWebTokenError",
  "message": "invalid signature",
  "stack":
      JsonWebTokenError: invalid signature
          at U:\Coding\MCShop-API\node_modules\jsonwebtoken\verify.js:171:19
          at getSecret (U:\Coding\MCShop-API\node_modules\jsonwebtoken\verify.js:97:14)
          at module.exports (U:\Coding\MCShop-API\node_modules\jsonwebtoken\verify.js:101:10)
          at verifyJWTToken (U:\Coding\MCShop-API\src\crypto.ts:28:37)
          at U:\Coding\MCShop-API\src\app.ts:39:45
          at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (U:\Coding\MCShop-API\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
          at trim_prefix (U:\Coding\MCShop-API\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:328:13)
          at U:\Coding\MCShop-API\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:286:9
          at Function.process_params (U:\Coding\MCShop-API\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:346:12)
          at next (U:\Coding\MCShop-API\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:280:10)
  "name": "JsonWebTokenError"
}
```

I have also attached the crypto.ts file that handles the JSON Web Tokens for my application.

```
import crypto from 'crypto';
import { readFileSync } from 'fs';
import { JwtPayload, sign, verify } from 'jsonwebtoken';
import { logger } from './app';

export function generateRSAKeyPair() {
    const { privateKey, publicKey } = crypto.generateKeyPairSync('rsa', {
        modulusLength: 512,
        publicKeyEncoding: { type: 'pkcs1', format: 'pem' },
        privateKeyEncoding: { type: 'pkcs1', format: 'pem' }
    });

    return { privateKey, publicKey };
}

export function generateJWTToken(admin: boolean, username: string) {
    const key = readFileSync('private.key', { encoding: 'utf-8', flag: 'r' });
    return sign({
        admin,
        username
    }, key, { algorithm: 'RS256' });
}

export function verifyJWTToken(token: string) {
    try {
        const key = readFileSync('public.key', { encoding: 'utf-8', flag: 'r' });
        const verifiedToken = verify(token, key, { algorithms: ['RS256'] }) as JwtPayload;
        if (!verifiedToken) return false;
        return verifiedToken

    } catch (error) {
        logger.fatal(error);
        return false;
    }
}
```

I have confirmed the following:

- The key variable is not undefined and is fetching the contents of the file.
- readFileSync does not use caching.
- The values that get passed into the function are valid.
- The attempted JWT is indeed valid confirmed by JWT.io [image: jwt.io]

I suspect there might be an error in how I'm handling the keys or in the JWT library version.

Can someone help me identify the root cause of the "invalid signature" error and suggest potential solutions? Any insights or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I remember I faced the same issue last year, and filed issue in github (https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken/issues/915). I was testing using `Postman` and the token was overridden by a parent collection and there was no issue in the package. You might test using any API Client tool to ensure you are sending the valid token.

Comment: I am intentionally using the inherited key as I set it the authentication key on the parent collection and dont need to worry about it for each individual request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I remember I faced the same issue last year, and filed an issue in [github](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken/issues/915). I was testing using Postman and the token was overridden by a parent collection and there was no issue in the package. You might ensure the valid tokens are not overridden by non-valid tokens.

Answer (score 2):

I ran your code and it was fine. I had to change the `modulusLength`, which is the key size in bits. For RS256 you would therefore set it to `256 * 8 = 2048`. You should be able to copy the 3 below files into a folder, then run these commands:

```bash
npm install
npm start
```

**index.ts**

```js
import crypto from 'crypto';
import { readFileSync, writeFileSync } from 'fs';
import { JwtPayload, sign, verify } from 'jsonwebtoken';

export function generateRSAKeyPair() {
    const { privateKey, publicKey } = crypto.generateKeyPairSync('rsa', {
        modulusLength: 2048,
        publicKeyEncoding: { type: 'pkcs1', format: 'pem' },
        privateKeyEncoding: { type: 'pkcs1', format: 'pem' }
    });

    return { privateKey, publicKey };
}

export function generateJWTToken(admin: boolean, username: string) {
    const key = readFileSync('private.key', { encoding: 'utf-8', flag: 'r' });
    return sign({
        admin,
        username
    }, key, { algorithm: 'RS256' });
}

export function verifyJWTToken(token: string) {
    const key = readFileSync('public.key', { encoding: 'utf-8', flag: 'r' });
    const verifiedToken = verify(token, key, { algorithms: ['RS256'] }) as JwtPayload;
    if (!verifiedToken) return false;
    return verifiedToken
}

const { privateKey, publicKey } = generateRSAKeyPair();
writeFileSync('./private.key', privateKey);
writeFileSync('./public.key', publicKey);
const token = generateJWTToken(true, 'john doe');
console.log(token);
const result = verifyJWTToken(token);
console.log(`Result is ${JSON.stringify(result)}`)
```

**package.json**

```json
{
  "name": "demo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsx ./index.ts"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^20.11.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.2",
    "tsx": "^4.7.0",
    "typescript": "^5.3.3"
  }
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "strict": true,
      "target": "ES2022",
      "lib": ["ES2022"],
      "module":"ES2022",
      "moduleResolution": "Node",
      "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
      "sourceMap": false
    },
    "include": [
      "*.ts"
    ],
    "exclude": [
      "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Apologies for wasting your time! Issue managed to get resolved, postman does not auto-save when you update authentication tokens in a collection, however, it does so upon doing it in a request. Once the cooldown is gone will mark this as the bounty winner if  Bassam A does not make their comment an answer.